# Python Reportlab combine paragraph

Tags: python, python-2.7, reportlab

I hope you can help me trying to combine a paragraph, my style is called "cursiva" and works perfectly also I have other's but it's the same if I change cursiva to other one. the issue is that If I use this coude o get this.

[image]

As you can see guys it shows with a line break and I need it shows togetter.

The problem is that i need to make it like this (one, one) togetter because I need to use two styles, the issue here is that I'm using arial narrrow so if I use italic or bold I need to use each one by separate because the typography does not alow me to use "< i >italic text< /i > ", so I need to use  two different styles that actually works fine by separate.

how can I achive this?

```
cursiva = ParagraphStyle('cursiva')
cursiva.fontSize = 8
cursiva.fontName= "Arialni"

incertidumbre=[]

incertidumbre.extend([Paragraph("one", cursiva), Paragraph("one", cursiva)])
```

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2):

The question you are asking is actually caused by a workaround for a different problem, namely that you don't know how to register font families in Reportlab. Because that is what is needed to make `<i>` and `<b>` work.

So you probably already managed to add a custom font, so the first part should look familiar, the final line is probably the missing link. It is registering the combination of these fonts a family.

```
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arialn', 'Arialn.ttf'))   
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arialnb', 'Arialnb.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arialni', 'Arialni.ttf'))
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arialnbi', 'Arialnbi.ttf'))

registerFontFamily('Arialn',normal='Arialn',bold='Arialnb',italic='Arialni',boldItalic='Arialnbi')
```